# Duplicate element in list x amount of times based off another list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of numbers and a list of strings

```
a = ['2', '2', '3', '4']
b = [' ', 'A', 'B', 'C']
```

I want to duplicate each string in `b` `a` times making my output look like:

```
[' ', ' ', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']
```

I've tried using `map` a bunch of different ways. Also would this be easier to do if I just switched the lists to `numpy` arrays and dealing it with that package.

Comment: You don't have numbers, you only have strings. (And it would be better to actually have numbers...)

Comment: Are the strings always exactly one character long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension, you will need to cast the string-version of your numbers to integers though using `map(int, a)`.

```
[z for x,y in zip(map(int,a), b) for z in x*y]
```

Comment: this is probably the most clever and efficient, but will silently give the shorter answer for lists of different lengths

Comment: wow thank you so much, how did you learn this much about this stuff? I'm going to have to do this type of thing more in the future.

Comment: @ti7 Did "most" refer only to "clever" or also to "efficient"? [Benchmark](https://tio.run/##bZDNasMwEITveoq5RTLCtHUPJZBD2lv7CMYYuZGJwPpBUSD2y7taqb11DwNiNN9qFNZ09a57C3HfL3rGp7L6xpXEJI4MeaJO9@jQb5h9xEOuMA6bCdyqwI1LUgm6XNyNvEezDowR60svy/ofq/m@KuPaOXo7mqSjmhZdeFEHrVIOSPzhoYQQGWhs8DEhGatNYhQFRZP3yw2/ZsFKVApjCif0h5eDRJWO5PUwsKkYoOOZ5J3kIxuMWszUoi8fIWuHAQ26WiHlqDWO13e0dRVflJ0u6oi5tpVwdzvpeHp@ohGiREPMffjcjqPL7HGUSGLffwA) :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy oh, of the given answers as the dust seemed to be settling - you should add yours, especially to highlight the usefulness of `itertools`

Comment: @ti7 Alright, done. The two are btw not generally equivalent, James's only works for single-character strings (maybe that's always the case for the OP, but they refuse to clarify).

Answer (score 1):

Due to the issues of differently-sized lists and `zip()`, I'd `assert` and write out a generator

```py
def populate(a, b):
    assert len(a) == len(b), f"a(L{len(a)}) and b(L{len(b)}) must be the same length"
    for index in range(len(a)):
        for count in range(int(a[index])):
            yield b[index]
```

```py
>>> a = ['2', '2', '3', '4']
>>> b = [' ', 'A', 'B', 'C']
>>> list(populate(a,b))
[' ', ' ', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']
>>> b.append("D")
>>> list(populate(a,b))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in populate
AssertionError: a(L4) and b(L5) must be the same length
```

Comment: Or you could tell zip to be strict.

Comment: oh, finally added with 3.10 - convenient! https://peps.python.org/pep-0618/

Answer (score 0):

To do this, just loop through the possible indexes and add the values to a list `a` number of times:

```
results = []
for i in range(len(b)):
    for _ in range(int(a[i])):
        results.append(b[i])
```

This can also be done through list comprehension for a more compact solution:

```
results = [b[i] for i in range(len(b)) for _ in range(int(a[i]))]
```

Answer (score 0):

An `itertools` solution:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

a = ['2', '2', '3', '4']
b = [' ', 'A', 'B', 'C']

result = [*chain.from_iterable(map(repeat, b, map(int, a)))]

print(result)
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY07DgIxDET7nMLdJiiiYCloKGCPgRByUNBGysfyhoLTh3jTPHn05Bn61bXk@ULc2odLglA911LiBiFR4QrvFUO2wJ48VqUQrvCYTpOFgVlwnp7K7QIk3gR3wdKFYr99YxV92MuOMvSSIXTR64SkR7sFZ0FiyP1GY0z/Ju5Jjw7T2h8)):

```
[' ', ' ', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']
```

Comment: Also `list(Counter({y: int(x) for x,y in zip(a,b)}).elements())`, although I hear that solutions with `Counter` are boring ;-)

Comment: @Stef Could use `list(Counter(dict(zip(b, map(int, a)))).elements())` for that. But they only work if `b` doesn't have duplicates.

Answer (score -4):

Try this

```
MyList = []
For I in range(len(a)):
Num = int(a[I])
    For J in range(Num):
        MyList.append(b[I])
Print(MyList)
```

Sorry for weird formatting